# Download current minimal.master

Tags: custom-masterpage

I'm only able to be on a SubSite in a team site.

In there I can see all the things, I can download them all like v4.master, default.master etc... but the minimal.master won't download - how come?

I didn't make it, but I wanna use it on another site in our company

Answer (score 0):

What do you try to get that master page?
What error/message do you get?

Maybe the master your want is actually defined at the root level of the site collection... Try to get it from its masterpages catalog instead of the sub-site catalog.

Comment: I get network-error